# DLL Needed For Excel VBA Sleep()?

Tags: vba, sleep

When using:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Is it required to have some sort of DLL? If so, which DLL and where can I obtain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kernel32.dll` is part of Windows, and as such will be on every Windows OS based machine.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  The issue I was having I though was related to DLL's but it turned out to be a corrupted Excel file.  It's good to know about the kernel32.dll though so thanks!